# Prevent duplicate record insertion on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I search A lot.. but failed to implement.
here is my code, how i prevent duplicate insertion on page refresh,, (how i use viewstate, or any other method.... resposnse.redirect is not a solution in this scenario).

```
protected void btn_save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            System.Data.DataTable dt_plotid = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt_plotid = FghBAL.Admitting.GetMax_ByPlotID(txt_plot.Text);
            string plotid = dt_plotid.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            if (FghBAL.Alotee.InserAllotee(txt_alotee_name.Text.ToUpper(), ddl_alotee_sw.SelectedValue.ToUpper(), txt_alotee_fname.Text.ToUpper(), alotee_cnic, txt_alotee_phone.Text, txt_alotee_cellno.Text, txt_alotee_address.Text, txt_alotee_email.Text, plotid))
            {
                lbl_error_3.Visible = true;
                lbl_error_3.Text = "Add Successfully";
                txt_alotee_name.Enabled = false;
                ddl_alotee_sw.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_fname.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_cnic_1.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_cnic_2.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_cnic_3.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_phone.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_cellno.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_address.Enabled = false;
                txt_alotee_email.Enabled = false;
                System.Data.DataTable dt_alotee_data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt_alotee_data = FghBAL.Alotee.GetDatabyPlot_Id(plotid);
                grid_alotee.DataSource = dt_alotee_data;
                grid_alotee.DataBind();
                grid_alotee.Visible = true;
                btn_save_alotee.Visible = true;

                btn_link_another_alotee.Visible = true;
                lbl_grd_alotee.Visible = true;
                tabcontent3.Style.Add("height", "80%");
                //ViewState["dt_alotee_view"] = dt_alotee_data;
                btn_save_alotee.Enabled = false;
               // Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_error_3.Text = "Unable to add Allottee Information";
            }
        }
```

Comment: *resposnse.redirect is not a solution in this scenario* why?

Comment: because it moves to 1st tab.. but i want it stay on current tab.. im using multiple tabs on same page (tab are controlled by radio buttons)

Comment: Add a duplicate check logic in `InserAllotee` method.

Comment: i also used..   protected void btn_save_alotee_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txt_alotee_name.Enabled == true)
        { ---- code ---

Comment: I debug the code when i refresh page it does not go to btn_save_click() but record is inserted in db duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to indicate that a button event handler is triggered on a page refresh - which is odd. A page refresh results in a `GET` action. Changes to server side data should only be done in `POST` requests though. And button event handlers should only be called when a button is clicked. I can't tell from this code in what way your architecture is violating these stipulations.

Comment: I debug the code when i refresh page it does not go to btn_save_click() but record is inserted in db duplicate

Comment: If it does not go to this function, the record is not inserted from this function (or not at that point in time). Any other code that does inserts, beside the code you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use view state or session to store the flag when the page first loads and then change the flag value to true when you have inserted in the database get the full code from here :

http://dotnetready4u.blogspot.com/2015/01/avoid-repaeted-insertion-on-page-refresh.html